# How to read from database on C++ for authentication process?

Tags: c++, database, authentication

Im trying to create an authentication process on c++, include and read from a .txt file as database where user:pass are defined already.
Question is, how to declare variables "user/pass" for reading from .txt file and authenticate on c++.
Also how to include the .txt file to read from it and close after.

example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string user = "user";
    string pass = "pass";
    string username;
    string password;
    int counter = 0;
    int pcounter = 0;

    ifstream db1 = db1.txt;

       do {
        cout << "Username" << "\n";
        cin >> username;

            if(username != user){
                cout << "Wrong name!" << "\n\n";
            }

        counter++;
        if(counter == 3){
                return 0;
        }
            } while (user != username);




    cout << "Username is correct!" << "\n\n";


    cout << "Please enter your Password: \n";


    cin >> password;



        if (password != pass && pcounter <= 3) {

            cout << "Wrong Password, try again \n";
            pcounter++;
            cin >> password;
        }




if (username == user && password == pass){
    cout << "Access granted!";
}
}
```

Comment: If you're storing your password as plain-text you're in for a world of hurt. Please, at the absolute minimum use something like [Bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).

Comment: When you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of a program that supposedly work (i.e. it at least builds), then make sure the code you show us *also* builds. Please don't rewrite the code into the question, *copy-paste* it.

Comment: Good C++ references will have examples and instructions for reading data from a file.

Comment: Is this homework or a book assignment?  For industry purposes, you need to be a lot more careful and use some kind of encryption and decryption.

Comment: Sorry if I failed on giving al required info.. actually its my first project, Self thought and trying to improve (its just for practicing). I will deffinitively get into encryption/decryption in the future, but for now im just working step by step at this...